# I want to match a greedy string "ha" more than one time, but it is giving only one match.

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
import re
x=""" hi i am laughing like hahahahahahaha. and i use it regularly"""
y=re.compile(r'(ha){1,5}')
z=y.search(x)
print z.group()
```

I want to match `ha` more than one time here. But it is matching only once.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking - include a problem statement in the question

Comment: `>>> import re
>>> x=""" hi i am laughing like hahahahahahaha. and i use it regularly"""
>>> y=re.compile(r'(ha){1,5}')
>>> z=y.search(x)
>>> print z.group()
hahahahaha`

This is the output from my python interpreter.. your code is correct...

Comment: In the string x i have given ha for seven times.  the code i have given prints only on ha. But i want 5 times it need to be print. my target to print hahahahaha out of 7 ha's. The code is giving only one.

Answer (score 1):

So above is working as expected:

```
>>> x=""" hi i am laughing like hahahahahahaha. and i use it regularly"""
>>> import re
>>> y=re.compile(r'(ha){1,5}')
>>> z=y.search(x)
>>> z.group()
'hahahahaha'
```

As you have mentioned in your statement to search for ha in range {1,5} and giving you the greedy match max till 5. But if you want it to match all occurrence then you can achieve it by this (+ is greedy)

```
>>> y=re.compile(r'(ha)+')
>>> z=y.search(x)
>>> z.group()
'hahahahahahaha'
```

Answer (score 0):

`re.search` finds (at most) a single match. To find multiple matches you can use `re.findall`, which returns a list of matching strings:

```
import re

x = """ hi i am laughing like hahahahahahaha. and i use it regularly"""
y = re.compile(r'(ha)')
print(y.findall(x))
```

**output**

```
['ha', 'ha', 'ha', 'ha', 'ha', 'ha', 'ha']
```

If you want actual Match objects rather than strings you can use `re.finditer`:

```
import re

x = """ hi i am laughing like hahahahahahaha. and i use it regularly"""
y = re.compile(r'(ha)')
for m in y.finditer(x):
    print(m)
```

**output**

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(23, 25), match='ha'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(25, 27), match='ha'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(27, 29), match='ha'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(29, 31), match='ha'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(31, 33), match='ha'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(33, 35), match='ha'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(35, 37), match='ha'>
```

---

If you want to find all occurrences of the *repeating* pattern, you need a slightly different strategy. One way to do it is to use `re.search` and chop the target string at the match point & search again until no more matches are found.

```
import re

x = """ hi i am laughing like hahahahahahaha. and i use it regularly"""
y = re.compile(r'(ha){1,5}')
patlen = 2

target = str(x)
while True:
    m = y.search(target)
    if not m:
        break
    target = target[patlen + m.start(0):]
    print(m.group(0))
```

**output**

```
hahahahaha
hahahahaha
hahahahaha
hahahaha
hahaha
haha
ha
```